# How is the math calculated in coef_ in the svc model?

Tags: python, coefficients

[image]
and this is my code

```
#SVM dengan kernel Linear
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1.0).fit(x_train, y_train)
coef = model.coef_

#Print co-efficient dari fitur
for i in range(0, nFeatures):
    print (samples.columns[i],":", coef[0][i])
```

and the result is :

```
PAY_0 : 0.22633744855967078
PAY_2 : 0.26406035665294925
PAY_3 : -0.07544581618655694
PAY_4 : -0.11316872427983539
PAY_5 : -0.22633744855967078
PAY_6 : -0.1886145404663923
```

i dont understand how does the coef_ work. Can someone explain me how to calculate the coeficient?

Comment: Too broad for a Stack Overflow question. Reading the Wikipedia article on [Support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) might get you started.

Comment: you are trying to a fit a linear function `y = w^Tx + b`. w is `coef_`, and `b` is `intercept_`.